# SQL Query to get the sum by joining the tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables `Trial1`, `TrialMid` and `Trial2`. The tables are as follows :

Trial1:

```
ID     Location    Numbers
--------------------------
TR1    US           890
TR2    AME          876
TR3    HUY           78
```

TrialMid

```
ID       Trial2Id    Area    Trial1id
----------------------------------------
TRM01       tr11       45       TR1
TRM02       tr11      345       TR1
TRM03       tr22      456       TR1
```

Trial2

```
ID       Name         Area    Reference
-----------------------------------------
tr11       Guza       897      324
tr22       asd        876       12
```

These are the three tables and I want to get the ID from `Trial2` using the Id from `Trial1`.

I want this output (using the `Trial1id`):

```
ID 
-----
tr11
tr22
```

I also want to get the count of the `Trial2` Ids but I can't use "group by".
The challenge I am facing is that the query that I want is to get the result as :

```
Total    Trial1
----------------
2         TR1



Id        Trial1
-----------------
tr11       TR1
tr22       TR1
```

I want to get the Ids from the table `Trial2` and not from `TrialMid`. If I use count() by using group by it is giving me result as

```
Total    Trial1
-----------------
 2        TR1
 1        TR1
```

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different database products. Which one do you actually use?

Comment: @Shadow I use ms sql server. The query remains the same still?? I am new to this database things.

Comment: Different database products implement sql differently. Unless your query uses really core sql features only, it will not be the same across different products.

Comment: What's the logic in order to return the row `2     |    TR1`, but not `1     |    TR1` ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Cause there are two tr11 in TrialMid and 1 tr22.

Comment: I mean, why do you want to get  `2     |    TR1` **only** ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I want to get 2 TR1 because ( tr11 and tr22 ) are both part of TR1. I don't want to see multiple tr11 or tr22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very hard to follow.  But I think you might be asking for the number of distinct `Trial2Id`s in the "mid" table for each `Trialid`.  If so:

```
select trial1id, count(distinct Trial2Id )
from TrialMid
group by trial1id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select trial1id,count(*) as total
from
(
select t.id as trial2id,t1.id as trial1id,row_number() over(partition by tm.Trial2Id order by tm.Area desc) as rn
from Trial2 t inner join TrialMid tm on t.id=tm.Trial2Id
inner join Trial1 t1 on tm.Trial1id=t1.id
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: What is A and rn? Cause Error is showing as "No Coulmn was specified for column 3 of 'A' " and in rn - "Cannot find column name "rn" "

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand you're looking for a *window function* including `PARTITION BY` clause as mentioning that *you can't use "group by"* :

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.ID AS "Total", 
       COUNT(T2.ID) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ID, T2.ID) AS "Trial1"
  FROM TrialMid TM
  JOIN Trial2 T2
    ON T2.ID = TM.Trial2Id
  JOIN Trial1 T1
    ON T1.ID = TM.Trial1Id

Total   Trial1
tr11    2
tr22    1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e6dc04fe8aec9faf8b3868d028f98a8b)</kbd>